# Get Schema of all sObjects in one Api Call, like Schema Builder

Tags: rest-api, api, schema, schema-builder

I am building a web tool to get the schema of a particular sObject, or an entire org, and save it as a Json file using the SalesForce Rest API.

To do this, I am first getting a list of all the sObjects from `/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/`, then calling `/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/{SOBJECT_NAME}/describe` on each one of them to get the schema.

This approach works, but needs one api call for each object.
Using the Batch Api can reduce the api calls by a factor of 25, but the data still needs a lot of resource-intensive post processing, which might be an issue on lower-powered devices.

I was poking around Schema Builder, and found that it loads a complete Schema of the org as a Json Object from the endpoint `salesforce.com/_ui/platform/schema/ui/schemabuilder/SchemaBuilderServlet`.

The loaded Json has all the objects of the org along with the fields and children, and needs no further processing.
Eg:

```js
"objs":{
    "ConsumptionSchedule":{
        "afl":true,
        "h":false,
        "l":"Consumption Schedule",
        "n":"ConsumptionSchedule",
        "rflds":{
        "BillingTermUnit":{
            "dt":"e",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Picklist() ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=BillingTermUnit&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"BillingTermUnit",
            "l":"Billing Term Unit",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"BillingTermUnit"
        },
        "CreatedBy":{
            "dt":"Y",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Lookup(User) ",
            "d":[
            "User"
            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=CreatedBy&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"CreatedBy",
            "l":"Created By",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"CreatedBy"
        },
        "LastModifiedBy":{
            "dt":"Y",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Lookup(User) ",
            "d":[
            "User"
            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=LastModifiedBy&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"LastModifiedBy",
            "l":"Last Modified By",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"LastModifiedBy"
        },
        "RatingMethod":{
            "dt":"e",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Picklist() ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=RatingMethod&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"RatingMethod",
            "l":"Rating Method",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"RatingMethod"
        },
        "Type":{
            "dt":"e",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Picklist() ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Type&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"Type",
            "l":"Type",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"Type"
        }
        },
        "u":"/p/setup/layout/LayoutFieldList?type=ConsumptionSchedule&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
        "filter_opts":[
        "sel",
        "std"
        ],
        "plu":"/ui/setup/layout/PageLayouts?type=ConsumptionSchedule&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleLayouts",
        "le":11460.0,
        "flds":{
        "IsActive":{
            "dt":"B",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":false,
            "t":"Checkbox ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=IsActive&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"IsActive",
            "l":"Active",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"IsActive"
        },
        "BillingTerm":{
            "dt":"N",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Number(9, 0) ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=BillingTerm&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"BillingTerm",
            "l":"Billing Term",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"BillingTerm"
        },
        "BillingTermUnit":{
            "dt":"e",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Picklist() ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=BillingTermUnit&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"BillingTermUnit",
            "l":"Billing Term Unit",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"BillingTermUnit"
        },
        "Name":{
            "dt":"S",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Text(255) ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Name&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"Name",
            "l":"Consumption Schedule Name",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"Name"
        },
        "CreatedBy":{
            "dt":"Y",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Lookup(User) ",
            "d":[
            "User"
            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=CreatedBy&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"CreatedBy",
            "l":"Created By",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"CreatedBy"
        },
        "CreatedDate":{
            "dt":"F",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Date/Time ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=CreatedDate&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"CreatedDate",
            "l":"Created Date",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"CreatedDate"
        },
        "Description":{
            "dt":"J",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":false,
            "t":"Long Text Area(32000) ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Description&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"Description",
            "l":"Description",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"Description"
        },
        "LastModifiedBy":{
            "dt":"Y",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Lookup(User) ",
            "d":[
            "User"
            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=LastModifiedBy&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"LastModifiedBy",
            "l":"Last Modified By",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"LastModifiedBy"
        },
        "LastModifiedDate":{
            "dt":"F",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Date/Time ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=LastModifiedDate&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"LastModifiedDate",
            "l":"Last Modified Date",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"LastModifiedDate"
        },
        "MatchingAttribute":{
            "dt":"S",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":false,
            "t":"Text(255) ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=MatchingAttribute&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"MatchingAttribute",
            "l":"Matching Attribute",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"MatchingAttribute"
        },
        "NumberOfRates":{
            "dt":"1",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":false,
            "t":"Roll-Up Summary (COUNT Consumption Rate) ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=NumberOfRates&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"NumberOfRates",
            "l":"Number of Consumption Rates",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"NumberOfRates"
        },
        "RatingMethod":{
            "dt":"e",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Picklist() ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=RatingMethod&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"RatingMethod",
            "l":"Rating Method",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"RatingMethod"
        },
        "Type":{
            "dt":"e",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":true,
            "t":"Picklist() ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Type&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"lu",
            "id":"Type",
            "l":"Type",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"Type"
        },
        "UnitOfMeasure":{
            "dt":"L",
            "eid":"ConsumptionSchedule",
            "r":false,
            "t":"Picklist ",
            "d":[

            ],
            "u":"/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=UnitOfMeasure&type=ConsumptionSchedule&retURL=%2F_ui%2Fplatform%2Fschema%2Fui%2Fschemabuilder%2FSchemaBuilderUi&setupid=ConsumptionScheduleFields",
            "rel":"",
            "id":"UnitOfMeasure",
            "l":"Unit of Measure",
            "cust":false,
            "n":"UnitOfMeasure"
        }
        },
        "sblitemid":"0GI6g000001tfp0",
        "id":"ConsumptionSchedule",
        "to":10488.0,
        "cust":false
    }

}
```

My question is: Can this object be retrieved from the Rest/Soap Api directly? If not, what is the best way to generate the Schema with minimum Api calls and no modifications to the org (no custom Apex code, extension etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite REST resource would have been our suggestion but it has a limit of 25 sub-requests, same as Batch. A better out of the box solution is [describeSObjects()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm) in SOAP API:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
    ...
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:describeSObjects>
         <urn:sObjectType>Contact</urn:sObjectType>
         <urn:sObjectType>Account</urn:sObjectType>
      </urn:describeSObjects>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      ...
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <describeSObjectsResponse>
         <result>
            ...
            <label>Contact</label>
            <labelPlural>Contacts</labelPlural>
         </result>
         <result>
            ...
            <label>Account</label>
            <labelPlural>Accounts</labelPlural>
         </result>

      </describeSObjectsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The `describeSObjects()` call is limited to a maximum of 100 objects returned, a 4x improvement over the Batch option. To get the list of objects, call [describeGlobal()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describeglobal.htm). You will want to use the [Partner WSDL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180261/use-cases-for-enterprise-wsdl-vs-partner-wsdl) as your SOAP interface.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for a way to get direct access to the `salesforce.com/_ui/platform/schema/ui/schemabuilder/SchemaBuilderServlet` object through any Api, since it will save a lot of post processing. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `SchemaBuilderServlet` is part of Salesforce product but it's not exposed via an API. You might be able to reverse engineer its interface and use it at your own risk.

Comment: OK, I think that I will stick to the published Api's then. Is 25 sub-requests the best that I can do with the Rest Api? Implementing Soap in the browser will take a while.